# Javascript / Jquery Progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, progress-bar

I created a progress bar which basically works.

Html looks like this:

```
<div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
       </div>
</div>
```

And my script like this:

```
/* Progress bar */
$("#project_name").blur(function(){
    /* if input not empty progress */
    if($(this).val() !== '' && $(this).val().length > 1) {
        console.log("already written" + $(this).val().length);
    } else if($(this).val() !== '') {
        var progressbar = $('.progress-bar');
        progressbar.width(progressbar.width() + 40);

        console.log("not empty" + $(this).val().length);
    } else {
        console.log("empty");
    }

});
```

If the input field has a value the progress bar increases, if a click somewhere else afterwards.

But the problem I found is that if I keep clicking at the input field and out, the progress bar keeps increasing.

So I made an if statement which should solve, this but does not at the moment.

This:

```
if($(this).val() !== '' && $(this).val().length > 0) {
    console.log("already written" + $(this).val().length);
}
```

But it still does not work.
If I increase the value of the input it does not increase the progress bar anymore, but if I keep a value which I do not increase the progress bar keeps increases if I click in and out.

Comment: Doesn't `$(this).val() !== ''`  generally imply that `$(this).val().length >= 1` ? You need to describe your progress "rule" e.g. what's 100% progress and what's 0% progress?

Comment: change >= 1 to > 1. So Basically I want to check if an input it empty or not, if it is not empty (if the user did write something) I want to increase the progressbar (percent number is not important)

Comment: Why use a **progress** bar if not to describe progress?

Comment: This is just an example code for myself, I am going to expand it later I just want to know where my mistake is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to increase the progress when the user adds more things to the input then you can do this.

More detailed explanation.

The way we keep track of whether the value increased in length is by setting the old length when the input has been selected (which is what is done via the `.focus` event).

When the input loses focus (`.blur` event) as per the original question, the old length is compared to the new length, if it's increased then we select the progress bar, but only if we hadn't previously increased it (since we add the class "increased" when we increase it).

Now for the reverse, we check if the input is empty. If we had previously increased the progress bar (it has class "increased") then we decrease it and remove that class.

```
//Store old value length
$("#project_name").focus(function() {
     $(this).data("oldLen",$(this).val()?$(this).val().length:0);
}); 

$("#project_name").blur(function(){
    var oldLen = $(this).data("oldLen") || 0; //Recall old length
    if($(this).val().length > oldLen) {  //Check if input is now longer
        var progressbar = $('.progress-bar:not(.increased)');
        if (progressbar.length > 0) {
            progressbar.width(progressbar.width() + 40);  
            progressbar.addClass("increased");         
           console.log("Input increased from "+oldLen +" to "+$(this).val().length);
        }
    } else if ($(this).val() == '') { 
         var progressbar = $('.progress-bar.increased');
         if (progressbar.length > 0) {
            progressbar.width(progressbar.width() - 40);  
            progressbar.removeClass("increased");         
           console.log("Input decreased from "+oldLen +" to "+$(this).val().length);
        }

    }
});
```

More generalised solution for multiple input elements. Here the assumption is you're increasing the progress for each element once it has data in it.
The change here is that you're keeping track of the progress bar increments via the "filled" class on the input and only increase progress if the input hadn't been filled before.

```
 //Not checking on length, just checking if more than 0
$("input").blur(function(){ // You can use other selectors for specific inputs like e.g. "#input1, #input2..."
    if($(this).val().length > 0 && !$(this).is("filled")) {  //Check if input is now filled
        var progressbar = $('.progress-bar');
        progressbar.width(progressbar.width() + 40);  
        $(this).addClass("filled");   //Mark input as filled                     

    } else if ($(this).val() == '' && $(this).is(".filled")) { 
         var progressbar = $('.progress-bar');
         progressbar.width(progressbar.width() - 40);  
         $(this).removeClass("filled");  //Mark as unfilled       
    }
});
```

Comment: No I do not want to increase it if a user puts more thing into one input, I should just increase once.

Comment: Updated to only increase once.

Comment: Thank you very much works, could you explain your code a little bit more if you dont mind. Thus how would you decrease if value is null just "<"?

Comment: Thanks alot, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Just a little question could I just chain other input elemts?

Comment: You'd have to change the logic a bit. I've made another update which should increase the progress by each "filled" input. You will need to tweak this as necessary since I don't know if it would work as is.

Comment: Hi again, works fine so far. But how you do this in a construction like this:

`code<fieldset class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="color" name="color">
                <option selected>Open Selection</option>
                <option value="{{ Input::old('color', $product->color)}}">Green</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>`

Comment: `$("input")` doesn't select dropdowns. You could use something like `$("input,select")` for this.

Comment: multiple input seems not working properly as well, if I click in and out it keeps increasing